# Excel add-in interaction with other Office365 applications

Tags: excel, office-addins

I'm exploring Office 365 development and I'm trying with Excel add-ins. 
One thing I'd like to was to interact with other Office applications, like Outlook, OneDrive and Word - from Excel.
For example, I'd like to send an email from an Excel table and/or insert the value of a cell in a Word document.
After searching the documentation, I couldn't find if this is possible, so I'd appreciate some help.
I'm new to Office development.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If that's your need, I think you don't need 365!

Comment: I know VBA but it's buggy and doesn't work on the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add-ins (Office.js) run in separate instances of browsers (controlled by the Office apps). This makes it difficult to pass messages between apps. Browser storage (cookies, localStorage and IndexedDatabase) can't consistently see each other's data/events when in separate instances. Because of this, we had to pass messages through our servers just to communicate between Excel, Word, and PowerPoint on the same device. Microsoft currently does not provide an API to communicate between add-ins in different apps.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation! Have you explored the CommonAPI yet? Uploading/downloading data from the Add-ins through the servers would leave some users unconfortable.

Comment: The CommonAPI are APIs that are the same for all apps. It does not mean that apps can communicate with each other using CommonAPI. Yes, I agree, many users/companies refuse to use a service where their data is uploaded off their device/network. Microsoft did recently release a shared storage API that may solve the problem, but may not quite be widely available: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-runtime/officeruntime.storage?view=common-js

Comment: Thanks for this info, it's really useful. It's hard to figure out what kind of strategy is Microsoft pursuing in terms of Office automation, it would be expectable to have Excel talk to Word and PowerPoint easily, but it doesn't seem to be the case.